# How to make a grid with random images in each cell - Processing

Tags: image-processing, processing

I'm trying to build a grid where each cell is filled by a random image in Processing. I have more than 500 images named img_xxx.jpg in the data folder. So far, I've accomplished a grid where the image that is displayed is random, but it's the same image for every cell. Hopefully you can help me out! Thanks.

```
final static byte GRID = 6, NUM = GRID*GRID;
PImage img;
int rand;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  noLoop();
  smooth();
  background(0);

  final PImage[] imgs = new PImage[NUM];
  final int tileW = width/GRID, tileH = height/GRID;
  rand = int(random(0,687)); 
  for (int idx=0; idx!=NUM; imgs[idx++] = loadImage("img_" + nf(rand,3)+ ".jpg"));

  for (int idx=0, row=0; row!=GRID; ++row)  for (int col=0; col!=GRID; 
      image(imgs[idx++], col++*tileW, row*tileH, tileW, tileH));

  img = get();
}

void draw() {
  background(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extreme abstraction you've done in your `for` loops is fun to write, but a huge pain to read. You need to recalculate `rand` at every image, so write your first `for` loop like this:

```
for (int idx=0; idx!=NUM; idx++) {
  rand = int(random(0, 687));
  imgs[idx] = loadImage("img_" + nf(rand, 3)+ ".jpg");
}
```

or, in your abstracted version:

```
for (int idx=0; idx!=NUM; imgs[idx++] = loadImage("img_" + nf(int(random(0,687)),3)+ ".jpg"));
```

(as a side note, I believe that `nf()` works on floats in newer versions of Processing, so you wouldn't need that `int()` command)

You might run into issues with memory because the images might not all load in time before you save them with `img = get();`. One way to solve this is to build in waiting time between loading the images and displaying them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, it's really abstract, I ended up changing mostly everything